# I'm try to fetch audits list.in backend i'm using python.python2 i'm getting data but in python3 i can't

Tags: java, android, python-3.x, realm

```
 private void fetchAudits() {
        showProgressDialog();
        Call<RealmList<Audit>> call = ServiceAdapter.getService().fetchAudits();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<RealmList<Audit>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RealmList<Audit>> call, final Response<RealmList<Audit>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                    realm.beginTransaction();
                    for (Audit audit : response.body()) {
                        Audit realmAudit = realm.where(Audit.class).equalTo("id", audit.getId()).findFirst();
                        if (realmAudit == null) {
                            realm.insert(audit);
                        }
                    }
                    realm.commitTransaction();
//                    realm.close();
                    loadAudits();
                } else {
                    try {
                        assert response.errorBody() != null;
                        Toast.makeText(AuditsListActivity.this, response.errorBody().string(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("Fetch audits", "Audits", e);
                        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
                        Toast.makeText(AuditsListActivity.this, "No audits found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }`enter code here`
                }
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
```

I'm try to fetch audits list.in backend i'm using python.python2 i'm getting data but in python3 i can't.suggest any solution for me.

my logcat error:
 Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Failed to parse date ["2020-02-22T08:23:58.506000"]: No time zone indicator
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.util.ISO8601Utils.parse(ISO8601Utils.java:274)
        at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:149)
        at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.read(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:128) 
        at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.read(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:44) 
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131) 
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222) 
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41) 
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82) 
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61) 
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:39) 
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27) 
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:122) 
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:217) 
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:116) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206) 
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

Comment: It is difficult to understand the problem when we cannot see any logcat error that you are having. Please include any error logs that you might be seeing in your logcat. Also, please check if you have the internet permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.